# Can only run a script with bash -x

Tags: bash, cron

I wrote a small script with an if statement in it

```
#!/bin/sh
if
....
fi
```

Then I wanted to run the script as a Cronjob but it was not working.

If I start the script with:

```
sudo bash -x ./test.sh
```

it is executed fine.

If I start the script with `./test.sh` nothing happens.

Any idea what is happening here and why I can not run the script as a cronjob?

Comment: It's probably not executable. Try `chmod +x test.sh`. Then you should be able to run it with cron and `./test.sh`. If cron fails but the other works, it's probably an issue with the environment under cron -- probably your `$PATH`.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. If I make the file executable I can call ./test.sh again but still nothing happens.

Comment: This might help: `sh` ([Bourne-shell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bourne_shell)) is usally not `bash` ([Bourne-again shell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bash_(Unix_shell))).

Comment: Show your cronjob.

Comment: */2 * * * * /home/user/test.sh

I tried changing #!/bin/sh to #!/bin/bash but this didn't help also

Comment: The other difference here that doesn't seem to have been addressed is whether you're running it under `sudo` -- does the script require that? Does it work if you just run `bash -x ./test.sh` without `sudo`?

Comment: bash -x ./test.sh works fine. However if the if statement is not met a further script is called which requires sudo in any case

Comment: This might help: [How to debug a bash script?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/155551/74329)

Comment: Please follow the [cron tab wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/cron/info) steps to debug this job.

Comment: Ok the problem is described here and is also the solution to my problem: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/464595/cronjob-wont-run-properly
Just add a PATH="$PATH:/usr/sbin:/sbin" to the beginning of the script
Thank you for all your help